# What does this line of solidity do (new Deed).value(msg.value)(msg.sender)?

Tags: solidity

ENS's HashRegistrarSimplified has [a line](https://github.com/ethereum/ens/blob/master/contracts/HashRegistrarSimplified.sol?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L355) I'm having trouble understanding. Inlined:

```
function newBid(bytes32 sealedBid) payable {
  if (address(sealedBids[msg.sender][sealedBid]) > 0) throw;
  if (msg.value < minPrice) throw;

  // Creates a new hash contract with the owner
  Deed newBid = (new Deed).value(msg.value)(msg.sender);
  sealedBids[msg.sender][sealedBid] = newBid;
  NewBid(sealedBid, msg.sender, msg.value);
}
```

It targets v0.4.0, if that makes a difference. The best I've been able to figure is:

```
(new Deed) // calls the constructor but with no arguments?
          .value(msg.value) // calls the accessor for value?
                           (msg.sender) // I'm pretty confused
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's equivalent to:

```
var constructor = (new Deed);
var constructorWithValue = constructor.value(msg.value);
Deed newBid = constructorWithValue(msg.sender);
```

---

It calls the constructor with `msg.sender` argument and forwards `msg.value` value with the call.

Without the value it would look like this

```
Deed newBid = new Deed(msg.sender)
```

and would forward 0 value as the default.

Comment: I was trying to decipher it but what confused me the most was the parenthesis in `(new Deed)` - I think in most other languages having parenthesis around it already creates the instance and you can't add values to constructor after that

Comment: You're missing `msg.sender` from the last line

Comment: I also forgot to assign the constructor with value. I don't know why this doesn't work: `constructor = constructor.value(msg.value);`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! What do you mean by "forwards msg.value value with the call"? Where can I find documentation on which methods are defined on constructors?

Comment: I've found an example in the docs: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html#creating-contracts-via-new but I'm not sure how this works. Does the parser special-case this? Do all functions have a .value() member?

Comment: Oh, after looking at solidity's source code I've figured it out. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I know that `call`, `delegatecall`, `callcode`,  functions called on other contracts via Solidity's contract abstraction all support gas() and value(). Constructors, `send`, `transfer` don't allow setting gas(), no idea why. Please share your findings.